# Find point between two points with specific distance from one of the points in polar coordinates

Tags: c#, polar-coordinates

I have 2 points in polar coordinates and need to find point between them with certain % of distance from one to other.

Let's say I have point 1 at 30° & 0.73r and point 2 at 172° & 0.98r, now I need to find point between them that is only let's say goes 0.3 of the way from point 1 towards point 2.

Note: Without conversions in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: What have yo tried? Did you google? We are not a code-writing service! Do take the tour and read the help pages!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't demonstrate that the OP knows how to solve the problem *mathematically*, which would be required before trying to implement it in code and the maths is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

In vectors (vector in the mathematical sense):

```
Vec_x = Vec_P1 + 0.3 * (Vec_P2 - Vec_P1)
```

Now you just need to find out how to work with vectors in polar coordinates and how to translate this to C#, but at least you have a starting point.